# How to find the firefox version from within a XUL app

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have a firefox addon which works for firefox version 3.0 onwards. However, a particular feature works only for FF 3.5 onwards.

I wanted to check from my addon's code that if the FF version is less than 3.5 then I shall disable the particular feature. Can someone please tell me how can I find out FF version from my addon's code?

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: Of course you could also build two totally different versions of the extension, with a different min/max version in the install.rdf, but that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's just `Application.version` -- it returns a String like `'3.6.8'`.